# Swift how to move UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, storyboard

I have an `infoButton` UIButton outlet in my swift file. This button is originally placed in the storyboard with the following constraints:

[image: Constraints picture]

I want to move this button down by 50 pixels depending if `NoAds` boolean is true or false.

I have tried doing this, but I can't seem to move it.

```
if NoAds{
            print("No Ads")
            infoButton.center.y = infoButton.center.y - 50
        }else{
            print("Ads")
            loadBanner()
        }
```

I assume this should be an easy fix?

EDIT: The ad is a standard google ad banner which is 320 wide and 50 high.

Comment: you are set ads view height constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. have an outlet for the top constraint 
   [image]
2. change the `topConstraint.constant`

like this:

```
if NoAds{
        print("No Ads")
        //topConstraint.constant -= 50
        topConstraint.constant = 50 // Avoid using -= or +=  if this func will call a lot of time
}else{
        print("Ads")

        // set the default constant you want
        topConstraint.constant = 100
        loadBanner()
}
```

Comment: How to set in default position of button in else condition?

Comment: topConstraint.constant = your constant

Comment: Avoid using `-=` or `+=` for constraint constants if they should only be one value or another. Just set it to 50 or 100, don't do math on it. Or you can have cases where you'll do the adjustment too many times in one direction and shift everything incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `IBOutlet` to connect to the constraint as @wilson-xj describes.

Then use the following code to animate the change to the constraint. This will add some polish and allow the ad to slide in/out nicely instead of jarring the user by instantly shifting content they may be interacting with.

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.30) { () -> Void in
    self.topConstraint.constant = constraintConstant // 50 or 100 etc
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would probably be to add the constraints and dynamically change the button, but if you didn't want to add another outlet and wanted to do this dynamically you could change the position of the button frame like so:

```
var X_Position:CGFloat? = startButton.frame.origin.x + 50 //add 50 to move button down page

var Y_Position:CGFloat? = startButton.frame.origin.y

startButton.frame = CGRectMake(X_Position, Y_Position, startButton.frame.width, startButton.frame.height)
```

This will redraw the button in the new position.

Comment: Changing the frame isn't reliable in Auto Layout. As soon as the layout gets updated the frame change gets overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Try this i hope it would be helpful This is mine code i am using!!
and i Assume that you all set the constraints like Top,Bottom,leading,Trailing space

```
 if NoAds
{
            print("No Ads")
           for item in self.view.constraints
                {
                    if item.firstItem .isKindOfClass(UIButton)
                    {
                        let newField = item.firstItem as! UIButton
                        if newField == buttonName && item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top
                        {
                            item.constant = -50
                            self.view .layoutIfNeeded()
                        }
                    }
                }
    }else{
            print("Ads")
        for item in self.view.constraints
                {
                    if item.firstItem .isKindOfClass(UIButton)
                    {
                        let newField = item.firstItem as! UIButton
                        if newField == buttonName && item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top
                        {
                            item.constant = 0
                            self.view .layoutIfNeeded()
                        }
                    }
                }
            loadBanner()
    }
```